# Getting piped data to functions

Tags: bash, pipe

**Example output**

Say I have a function, `a`:

```
function a() {
    read -r VALUE

    if [[ -n "$VALUE" ]]; then     # empty variable check
        echo "$VALUE"
    else
        echo "Default value"
    fi
}
```

So, to demonstrate piping to that function:

```
nick@nick-lt:~$ echo "Something" | a
Something
```

However, piping data to this function should be optional. So, this should also be valid. and give the following output:

```
nick@nick-lt:~$ a
Default value
```

However, the function hangs, as the `read` command waits for data from `stdin`.

**What I've tried**

Honestly not a lot, because I don't know much about this, and searching on Google returned very little.

Conceptually, I thought there might be a way to "push" an empty (or whitespace, whatever works) value to the `stdin` stream, so that even empty `stdin` at least has this value appended/prepended, triggering `read` and then simply trim off that first/last character. I didn't find a way to do this.

**Question**

How can I, if possible, make both of the above scenarios work for function `a`, so that piping is optional?

**EDIT**: Apologies, quickly written question. Should work properly now.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What is the use case for such a function? I'm not sure reading from standard input is more useful than simply taking an optional argument here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to check whether standard input (fd 0) is a terminal.  If so, don't read, because that will cause the user to have to enter something.

```
function a() {
    value=""

    if [ \! -t 0 ] ; then      # read only if fd 0 is a pipe (not a tty)
        read -r value
    fi

    if [ "$value" ] ; then     # if nonempty, print it!
        echo "$value"
    else
        echo "Default value"
    fi
}
```

I checked this on cygwin: `a` prints "Default value" and `echo 42 | a` prints "42".

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and works as expected on the two tests in the question (using `bash` on Linux)! I'll have to look into using `\! -t 0` and see if that brings any caveats of its own, but for the question it works.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- Syntactic, You need a space, before closing `]]`
- Algorithmic, You need the `-n` (non-zero length) variable test, not `-z` (zero length)

So:

```
if [[ -n "$VALUE" ]]; then
```

Or simply:

```
if [[ "$VALUE" ]]; then
```

As `[[` is a shell builtin, you don't strictly need the double quotes:

```
if [[ $VALUE ]]; then
```

Also refrain from using all uppercases as variable name, as these are usually used for denoting environment variables, and your defined one might somehow overwrite already existing one. So use lowercase variable name:

```
if [[ $value ]]; then
```

unless you are `export`-ing your variable, and strictly need it to be uppercased, also make sure it is not overwriting any already existing one.

Also, i would add a timeout to `read` e.g. `-t 5` for 5 seconds, and if no input is entered, print the default value. Also change the function name to something more meaningful.

---

Do:

```
function myfunc () { 
    read -rt5 value
    if [[ "$value" ]]; then 
        echo "$value"
    else 
        echo "Default value"
    fi 
    }
```

**Example:**

```
$ function myfunc () { read -rt5 value; if [[ "$value" ]]; then echo "$value"; else echo "Default value"; fi ;}

$ myfunc
Default value

$ echo "something" | myfunc
something

$ myfunc
foobar
foobar
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - if the function `a` is called without any piped information (i.e., `nick@nick-lt:~$ a`) then the words `default value` should be printed. How can I achieve this?